# How to enable Git Autocomplete in MacOS?

Tags: macos, zsh

I'm using Mac OS Monetary and Recently installed Git for a project. I followed the below steps to activate the Git Autocomplete feature for Git commands and Branch names. I got success in my Previous Macbook with MacOS Catalina, but it's not working on Monetary. **The Error is, "zsh: permission denied: /Users/username/.zshrc" when I run "`~/.zshrc`"**

**Steps Are:**

Run in Terminal

```
curl -o git-completion.bash https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash

curl -o _git https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.zsh

~/.zshrc
```

Update the File with

```
zstyle ':completion:*:*:git:*' script ~/.zsh/git-completion.bash
fpath=(~/.zsh $fpath)

autoload -Uz compinit && compinit
```

And Run

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Not sure where you got these instructions from but this appears to be trying to use the bash completion with zsh. Zsh comes with git completion and the only thing needed to enable it is the final line in `.zshrc`, i.e `autoload -Uz compinit && compinit`

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I edited the file with vim

```
sudo vim ~/.zshrc
```

provide your password and add the following to the end of the file

```
autoload -Uz compinit && compinit
```

relaunch your shell and you should have git completions

```
git checkout my_branch<tab>
```

should tab complete the branch name for you.

Comment: Can you please explain about the used commands?

Comment: sudo and git are pretty common. `autoload` is a zsh / korn shell thing. Read `man zshbuiltins` https://linux.die.net/man/1/zshbuiltins
> Equivalent to functions -u, with the exception of -X/+X and -w.
The flag -X may be used only inside a shell function, and may not be followed by a name. It causes the calling function to be marked for autoloading and then immediately loaded and executed, with the current array of positional parameters as arguments. This replaces the previous definition of the function. If no function definition is found, an error is printed and the function remains